# where is the connection between int fd = open("dateiname", O_CREAT | ACCESS_RIGHTS); and execlp("ls", "ls", (char*)NULL);?

Tags: c, linux

I have one question.
I have the following Code from an exercise:

```
#define ACCESS_RIGHTS O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR
    
     int main(void) {
     pid_t pid = fork();
     if (pid == 0) {
     int fd = open("dateiname", O_CREAT | ACCESS_RIGHTS);
    
    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
     close(fd);
    
     execlp("ls", "ls", (char*)NULL);
     } else {
     waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
     execlp("cat", "cat", "dateiname", (char*)NULL);
     }
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
     }
```

I do not understand the connection between

```
int fd = open("dateiname", O_CREAT | ACCESS_RIGHTS);
```

and

```
execlp("ls", "ls", (char*)NULL);
```

When the first code creates a file named "dateiname" and gives all the access rights.
How does the second code know, that it has to give the output from "ls" to the file "dateiname" ?
There is no paramater with the name of the file in execlp as an attribute.
How can execlp know?

My second question is: For what is this part of code?

```
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
         close(fd);
```

fd is copied to output like console, right? and then fd is closed. Why is that? I think that we do not have a duplicate and only an output in console?

Comment: What is there for `ls` to know? It will just print out all filenames...

Comment: Yes, I know that. But our solution says that it will print out all the filenames in the created file "dateiname"

Comment: There aren't filenames _in_ a file. There could be in a directory, but those are created with `mkdir`...

Comment: it's an implementation of a stdout redirection like when you call `ls > dateiname`

Comment: I do not understand. In Java for example, every time we have to give the parameters to another function. How does ls now that it has to do ">"-operation into "dateiname" ?

Comment: Because the `dup2()` in the child replaced the stdout by the file `fd`.

Comment: ahhh, and execlp automatically knows to do the ">" - operation to the stdoutput, but because it is replaced, it will do it to the filename, right? thank you!

Comment: Reading the documentation of called standard functions saves a lot of time, for you that you don't have to wait for comments or even an answer, and for us. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

is equivalent of:

```
close(1);
dup(fd);
```

it closes stdout and creates file descriptor that has value 1 and refers to 'dateiname'. So then every operation that writes to stdout (1) will write to dateiname. Like `printf("smth");` or in your case:

```
execlp("ls", "ls", (char*)NULL);
```